# Asymptotic (in)dependence of a maximum of an i.i.d. sequence of Gaussian random variables on a single random variable in this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Suppose that I have a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ where $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Denote the maximum of this sequence by $M_n=\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.

I am wondering about the dependence between the maximum $M_n$ and some random variable in that sequence $X_i$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  My intuition tells me that $M_n$ *should* be independent of any *given* $X_i$ as the sequence gets larger, since then an individual member of the sequence, $X_i$, doesn't "contribute" much to the maximum.  However, I am not sure whether this is in fact true.  Does anyone know of the existence of a formal proof?

If it turns out that maximum of this sequence is asymptotically independent of a particular random variable in the sequence, this would be helpful for the computation of a limit of expected value $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[f(X_i)g(M_n)]$ where expectations $E[f(X_i)]$ and $E[g(M_n)]$ can be easily computed.

Comment: What would be the property that $X_1$ and $M_n$ of are asymptotically independent when $n\to\infty$ since $(M_n)$ diverges almost surely?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question...  but, yes, $(M_n)$ diverges. In my particular problem though, $g(M_n)=\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}$ which converges a.s. to 1, and $E[f(X_1)]$ evaluates to a quantity which is a constant in the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$. I think I can evaluate those expectations separately and then multiply if $X_1$ and $M_n$ are independent (hence my question).

Comment: The question is what would be a precise mathematical statement that would correspond to an "asymptotic independence of $M_n$ and $X_1$". As you said, $g(M_n)\to1$ and constants are independent of everything hence $E[h(g(M_n))k(X_1)]\to h(1)E[k(X_1)]$ for every bounded continuous functions $h$ and $k$. Is this what you are after?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am after. So, as I understand you, $g(M_n)$ is essentially a degenerate random variable in the limit, and degenerate random variates are independent of everything else by construction...